# need help for javascript not working

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/Chinni123/qpqobso8/1/

on clicking cards it should validate if user not present in getcookie then it should return false and override the ahref and go to Cardspass.htm.This is not overriding

```
document.getElementById("myLink1").onclick = function () {
     var user = getCookie("username");
     alert(user);
     if (user === "") {
         alert("no user");
         return true;
     } else {


    alert("we user");
         window.frames.content.location = "/cards/Cardspass.htm";
         return false;
     }
 };


 function getCookie(cname) {
     var name = cname + "=";
     var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
     for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
         var c = ca[i];
         while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
         if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
             return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
         }
     }
     return "";
 }
```

I am new to jsfiddle and javascript.

Comment: Thank you @ danleyb2.  content is frame sibling frame. So, i think i need to mention. and i tried  with window.location does not work

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use cookies? If not, why not use local storage:

```
     document.getElementById("myLink1").onclick = function () {
         var user = localStorage.getItem("username");
         alert(user);
         if (!user) {
             alert("no user");
             location.href = "/cards/Cards.htm";
         } else {
             alert("we user");
             location.href = "/cards/Cardspass.htm";
         }
     };
```

and to set the key-value pair, wherever you do that:

```
localStorage.setItem("username", dataString);
```

Comment: Thank you @ Graham T. My problem is cardspass.htm is not displayed in "content" frame due to window.frames.content.location.              Cookies is working fine.       it does not return false(even though alert "we user is displayed") and override cards.htm  in ahref.

Comment: post your frames HTML in the fiddle